# Backwards stepwise regression code in R (using cross-validation as criteria)

Tags: beginner, r

I want to write code that does backward stepwise selection using cross-validation as a criterion.

I have only started learning R a month ago and I have almost zero programming experience prior to that. Hence, I would appreciate any comments on the code.

(I understand that there are issues with the backward stepwise selection process itself.)

```
rm(list=ls())
library(forecast)
library(fpp)
set.seed(1)

x1<-c(1:500)*runif(20,min=0,max=200)
x2<-c(1:500)*runif(20,min=0,max=200)

library(caret)
data(credit)
score <- credit$score 
log.savings <-log(credit$savings+1)
log.income <-log(credit$income+1)
log.address<- log(credit$time.address+1)
log.employed <- log(credit$time.employed+1)


################################## 


#Input
full.model<- score ~ log.savings + log.income + log.address + log.employed + x1 +x2  


# 1. Start with the full model 
counter=1
full <- lm(full.model)
scopevars<- attr(full$terms, "predvars") # list of model predicotrs 
n <- length(full$residuals);  # sample size
current_best <- full #what is the currenly the best model ? that would be our full model for now

while(T){ #process until we break the loop 

  best_cv <- CV(current_best)[1] #the CV of the current_best model
  temp <- summary(current_best) #summary output of the current_best model 
  p <- dim(temp$coefficients)[1]  # current model's size

  rnames <- rownames(temp$coefficients)  # list of terms in the current model

  compare <- matrix(NA,p,1) # create a matrix to store CV information 
  rownames(compare) <- rnames #name the matrix 


  #create a loop that drops one predictor at a time and calculates the CV of the regression when that predictor is dropped 
  #put all the information into "compare"
  #drop the variable that has the lowerst CV when it is dropped.

  for (i in 2:p) { 
    drop_var <- rnames[i] #variable to be deleted 
    f <- formula(current_best) #current formula 
    f <- as.formula(paste(f[2], "~", paste(f[3], drop_var, sep=" - "))) # modify the formula to drop the chosen variable (by subtracting it)
    new_fit <- lm(f)  # fit the modified model 
    compare[i]<-CV(new_fit)[1]
  }


  remove_var <-rownames(compare)[which.min(compare)] #drop is the varibale that is associate with the lowerst CV 
  update_cv <- compare[which.min(compare)] 

  if(update_cv>best_cv) break #we should not continue if dropping a variable will not improve Cv 

   write(paste("--- Dropping",counter, remove_var , update_cv, "\n"), file="") # output the variables we are dropping. 

  f <- formula(current_best) #current formula
  f <- as.formula(paste(f[2], "~", paste(f[3], remove_var , sep=" - ")));  # modify the formula to drop the chosen variable (by subtracting it)
  current_best <- lm(f)# we now have a new best model 
  counter=counter+1 #update our counter 
  next
} #end the while loop 
print(current_best)
CV(current_best)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good. I could not find important corrections to be made. I could find only some small cosmetic improvements - nothing serious.

For example. You do not need the `caret` package loaded for this task. You do not need to use `next` at the end of the `while` loop. It is good practice to keep your code in width of 80 characters. It improves readability a lot. See my code attached.

```
rm(list=ls())
gc()

library(forecast)
library(fpp)

set.seed(1)
x1 <- c(1:500) * runif(20, min=0, max=200)
x2 <- c(1:500) * runif(20, min=0, max=200)

data(credit)
score <- credit$score 
log.savings <- log(credit$savings+1)
log.income <- log(credit$income+1)
log.address <- log(credit$time.address+1)
log.employed <- log(credit$time.employed+1)


################################## 

#Input
full.model <- score ~ log.savings + log.income + log.address +
  log.employed + x1 +x2


# 1. Start with the full model 
counter <- 1L
full <- lm(full.model)

scopevars <- attr(full$terms, "predvars") # list of model predicotrs
n <- length(full$residuals)  # sample size
current_best <- full #what is the currenly the best model?
 # that would be our full model for now

while(T) { #process until we break the loop

  best_cv <- CV(current_best)[1] #the CV of the current_best model
  temp <- summary(current_best) #summary output of the current_best model 
  p <- dim(temp$coefficients)[1]  # current model's size

  rnames <- rownames(temp$coefficients)  # list of terms in the current model

  compare <- matrix(NA,p,1) # create a matrix to store CV information 
  rownames(compare) <- rnames #name the matrix 

  # create a loop that drops one predictor at a time and calculates
  # the CV of the regression when that predictor is dropped 
  # put all the information into "compare"
  # drop the variable that has the lowest CV when it is dropped.

  for (i in 2:p) { 
    drop_var <- rnames[i] #variable to be deleted 
    f <- formula(current_best) #current formula 
    f <- as.formula(paste(f[2], "~", paste(f[3], drop_var, sep=" - ")))
    # modify the formula to drop the chosen variable (by subtracting it)
    new_fit <- lm(f)  # fit the modified model 
    compare[i] <- CV(new_fit)[1]
  }

  remove_var <- rownames(compare)[which.min(compare)]
  # drop is the varibale that is associate with the lowest CV
  update_cv <- compare[which.min(compare)]

  if (update_cv > best_cv) break # we should not continue
  # if dropping a variable will not improve CV

  write(paste("--- Dropping", counter, remove_var , update_cv, "\n"), file="")
  # output the variables we are dropping

  f <- formula(current_best) #current formula
  f <- as.formula(paste(f[2], "~", paste(f[3], remove_var , sep=" - ")))
  # modify the formula to drop the chosen variable (by subtracting it)
  current_best <- lm(f) # we now have a new best model
  counter <- counter + 1L # update our counter
} #end the while loop 

print(current_best)
CV(current_best)
```